# laravel 5.3 textarea doesn't work has no action

Tags: textarea, laravel-5.3

I'm a web developer.
I have a problem.

/resources/views/add.blade.php

```
<textarea class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" rows="5"
   id="content" name="content" required="required">
   {{ empty($data['content']) ? old('content') : $data['content'] }}
</textarea>
```

NewsController.php

```
public function getUpdate($id)
{
    $news = News::find($id);

    if(empty($news->id)) {
        return view('news.update')->withErrors([trans('error.edit', ['value' => 'NewsUpdate'])]);
    }

    return view('news.update', 'data' => $news]);
}
```

like that coded, textarea "content" has no value.

Of course $data['content'] have value.

If coded like that text 'content' has value.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"
       id="content" name="content" 
       value="{{ empty($data['content']) ? old('content') : $data['content'] }}
       required="required">
```

Anyone help me.

Comment: Please explain your problem little more.

Comment: Is that your actual `HTML` it looks like you've missed a quote mark at the end of class: `class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"`

Comment: This is how my codes looks like for textarea "{!! Form::textarea('address', $data['address'],
      array('class' => 'form-control',
      'placeholder' =>'Address',
      'id' => 'address',
      'rows'=>3,
      'cols'=>20)) !!}"

Comment: Can you show the code for your controller methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry I have a mistake. I tried to $data['conntent'].
My spelling is false.

```
<textarea type="text" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" rows="5"
    id="content" name="content" value="{{ empty($data['content']) ? old('content') : $data['content'] }}"
    placeholder='@lang('menuview.News.Content')' required="required">{{  $data['content'] }}
</textarea>
```

Answer (score -2):

in your case:

```
<textarea class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" rows="5" id="content" name="content" required="required">
   <?php empty($data['content']) ? old('content') : $data['content']; ?>
</textarea>
```